# Standalone tool to synchronize two folders in windows?

Tags: windows, usb, synchronization

I keep data on a USB drive, but I also keep a copy of all of that data on a hard disk.  I like using the hard disk because it's faster and gives me a backup.  What standalone tools would work to keep the files on the disk and USB drive in sync?  I'd like a single command line executable or standalone GUI app that can do the job--something I could run off of the USB drive.  So, things like the MS Sync Tool wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used [Pathsync](http://www.cockos.com/pathsync/) before to do basically the same thing and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) is the tool of choice if you don't mind the sometimes counterintuitive (optional) GUI. It is like rsync in both directions, hence actual synchronization and not only mirroring. Also updates are made in an atomic way (if at all possible) so you are never left with a half-through update of a file.

Answer (score 2):

[Synctoy](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) is made by Microsoft and can be batched through command line. The only tricky part is that you have to use the GUI to create a 'sync set' and then refer to the sync set name in your batch script.

Answer (score 2):

**[Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx)** is by far the best tool I've found. It's even included in newer versions of Windows. It has a whole heap of options, but basically, the following command will make the destination directory an exact copy of the source directory:

```
robocopy C:\your\source\path D:\your\dest\path /MIR
```

Note that this not only copies files, but deletes them as well - if a file is not in the source directory it will be deleted from the destination directory, so be careful.

Answer (score 1):

[DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) - Also Rsync for Windows (see binaries **Without Installer**)

Answer (score 0):

[cwrsync - Rsync for Windows](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650)